# why i am getting 1 at the end of string in php?

Tags: php

I have written this code to take the sting from the textbox and want to replace any badwords with "***" but I don't know why I am getting one extra "1" at the end..you can have a look of output in the picture.

here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Mind Your Language </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="string">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  
  $badWords = ['badword1', 'badword2', 'badword3', 'badword4', 'badword5'];
  $string = $_POST['string'];
  
  foreach($badWords as $badWord) {
    $string1 = str_replace($badWord, "***", $string);
  }
  echo print_r($string1);
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: because you're echoing ___and___ printing; `print_r()` prints the string, a then returns a value, which you're then echoing

Comment: Try `echo print_r($string1, true);`

Answer (score 1):

[print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

If given a string, integer or float, the value itself will be printed. If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.

When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.

Either you need to use `echo print_r($string1, true);` or simply `print_r($string1);`